# Replacing '\x..' litteral string in Python

Tags: python, linux

I have directories that contains '\x..' characters such as '\x00' :

```
#ls
c\x00mb
```

and I want to rename them without these, since when I copy those files to windows they become unusable.
So my python script is going through those directories and detecting the problematic characters the following way:

```
if '\\x' in dir: # dir is the name of the current directory
```

First I thought I could get rid of this problem by using the `re` module in python:

```
new_dir_name = re.sub('\x00', r'', dir) # I am using \x00 as an example
```

But this didn't work. Is there a way I can replace thoses characters using python?

EDIT : 
in order to understand the char, when I pipe `ls` to `xxd` the '\' character appears in the ascii representation. In hexadecimal it shows '5c'

Comment: I'd start by doing an `os.listdir()` in python and verify what python thinks the string representation of those directory names looks like.

Comment: could be as easy as `new_dir_name = dir.replace('\0', '')`

Comment: os.listdir(dir_path) gives 'c\\x00mb'. Let me try the dir.replace

Comment: that seems to imply that your directory name has a *literal backslash* in the name. If it had and actual null character, it would look like `c\x00mb`.

Comment: Pipe the output of `ls` through `hexdump` to confirm which characters are *really* in the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) worked for me:

```
dir = r'foo\x00bar'
print dir
dir.replace(r'\x00', '')
print dir
```

Output is:

```
foo\x00bar
foobar
```

> **`string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`**
>
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

A regular expression could also work for the general case, but you'll have to escape the backslash so that `\x` itself isn't interpreted as a regular expression escape.

For the general case of removing `\x` followed by two hexadecimal digits:

```
import re
dir = r'foo\x1Dbar'
print dir
re.sub(r'\\x[0-9A-F]{2}', '', dir)
print dir
```

Output is:

```
foo\x1Dbar
foobar
```

Comment: you may want to explain why the regex failed,

Comment: the \x00 works but could that be expanded to a regex to take the others in consideration (for example with \x0A, \x0D...)

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre. answer updated with regex solution/explanation

Comment: No idea how it was in Python 2, but with Python 3.11 it does not work

Answer (score 2):

This interpreter session should show the difference between your dirname have an actual null character in it, versus having a backlash followed by an `x` followed by two `0`s.

```
>>> bad_dir_name = "c\x00mb"
>>> bad_dir_name
'c\x00mb'
>>> good_dir_name = bad_dir_name.replace("\x00", "")
>>> good_dir_name
'cmb'
>>>
>>> bad_dir_name2 = "c\\x00mb"
>>> bad_dir_name2
'c\\x00mb'
>>> good_dir_name2 = bad_dir_name2.replace("\\", "") # remove the backslash
>>> good_dir_name2
'cx00mb'
```

In either case, the `string.replace` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `\x` represents a hexadecimal character escape.

The answer provided by tavnab does not work for me.

The reason is that `string.replace` is not an inplace method. Also, in Python 3 the `print` function requires parentheses. So, the updated answer should be:

```
dir =  = r'foo\x00bar'
print(dir)
dir = dir.replace(r'\x00', '')
print(dir)
```

which then indeed produces the following output:

```
foo\x00bar
foobar
```

Comment: Does not work for me (Python 3.11). Still prints 'foo\x00bar'

Comment: On this third line, place an "r" in front of '\x00', or alternatively, add an additional backslash as in '\\x00'. I tried it in Python 3.9 and it's working. Is that working for you in 3.11?

Comment: J.Aldan: Yes, it does! Thanks!